# Firebase Authentication fails with FirebaseException: Instantiation of JsonResponse failed

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, firebase-authentication, google-signin

## Problem

I have just created an update for one of my `Xamarin.Forms` apps and now I have the problem that the **Firebase** sign-in workflow is suddenly broken **after** uploading the new **.aab** to Google Play. It has been working fine until now.

When I attempt to sign-in, the following error message appears in the device log after selecting the Google user account:

```
Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
11-18 16:49:57.295  Samsung SM-S901B    Verbose 5646    mono-stdout com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ Instantiation of JsonResponse failed! class com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzaac ]
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzwe.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.8:4)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzxc.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.8:9)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzxd.zzl(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.8:1)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzxa.zzh(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.8:25)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzwc.zzh(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.8:1)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzua.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.8:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzxl.zzb(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.8:13)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzxl.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.8:14)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzwr.zzq(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.8:4)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzuh.zzA(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.8:4)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzwd.zzu(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.8:5)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzvj.zzc(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.8:1)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzxe.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.8:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

This only affects the Release build which is signed by Google Play and therefore, I cannot replicate this in the debugger. When running the debug version, everything works as expected.

### Additional Info

Android Version: 13.0
Android Target API: 33

NuGet Packages (only seemingly relevant ones shown):

- Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2515
- Google.Apis 1.57.0
- Google.Apis.Auth 1.57.0
- Xamarin.Firebase.Auth 121.0.8
- Xamarin.Firebase.Common 120.1.2
- Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Auth 120.3.0

I am using the Google Sign-In button in my Android activity and I am not using the Web Authenticator (yet).

I use Android App Bundles (.aab) for publishing instead of uploading .apk files.

## What I've tried so far

I have checked all SHA certificate fingerprints (for Debug and Release builds as well as the signing certificate in my keystore and the one used by Google Play to sign the release) against the ones in the Firebase Console, google-services.json, Google Cloud Console and also the application restrictions for my Android API key.

Debugging does not yield the same outcome, so I've only managed to use the device log to get to the exception shown above.

Apart from that, I have upgraded to the latest versions of the Google and Firebase Auth libraries for Xamarin.Forms.

I'm a bit at a loss now. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to narrow this further down or has anyone experienced this problem before?

Comment: As a way around i turned off fullmode for code shrink and login started working again. For future ref if anybody faces same: you cando android.enableR8.fullMode=false in you android->gradle.properties. But this is just a workaround, we should configure pro guard to keep firebase auth classes: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/2124

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It works again.

The issue was unrelated to the signing certificates (which is usually the first go-to for these kind of problems) and the libraries that are being used.

This problem was actually caused by a small optimization which was causing the code shrinker to remove some Firebase related code. Disabling the code shrinker (temporarily) solved the issue.

Comment: How do it fix? If I want to use the code shrinker

Comment: Then you will have to configure [ProGuard](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/proguard) to exclude all relevant parts of the code that must be kept.

Answer (score 12):

in the proguard-rules.pro file add the following lines which should solve this issue,

```
-keep class com.google.firebase.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.firebase.**
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```

Comment: Yes, that's required when actually using ProGuard. When using ProGuard, it's required to potentially exclude more than just the Firebase and Google authentication libraries. I ended up disabling it altogether for my app.

Answer (score 5):

Update Firebase BOM, this is now [fixed](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#auth_v22-1-0) in Android BoM (Bill of Materials) version 32.2.0

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in my dot net MAUI app release build and it was fixed by disabling the R8 code shrinker in the MAUIapp.csproj file's properties and adding a new proguard-rules.pro file at the root of my project with the following lines:

```
-keep class com.google.firebase.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.firebase.**
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```