# Firebase Auth Instantiation of JsonResponse Failed

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I'm having a weird issue, in debug mode my app works fine, I'm suspecting that the proguard is doing something that I cannot log in.

### Error

[image]

### Proguard file

```
-keep class com.myapp.domain.model.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.conscrypt.**
-dontwarn org.bouncycastle.**
-dontwarn org.openjsse.**
```

All serialization classes are inside the model package, I'm about to do a new release, and the last version was working fine, I did not touch anything related to Proguard, just UI changes.

### What I have tried

- Invalidate/restart
- Add SHA-1 to firebase auth
- Check that authentication method (username/password) is enabled
- Check that proguard is not offuscating something related to auth
- Upgraded dependencies

### Dependencies

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:21.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.5.0'
```

As I mentioned, debug mode works correctly, I'm suspecting something is going on with my buildtype config (more about minifyEnabled)

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

I saw this response: [Firebase Authentication fails with FirebaseException: Instantiation of JsonResponse failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74492854/firebase-authentication-fails-with-firebaseexception-instantiation-of-jsonrespo)

But I cannot disable obfuscation on a release app

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, seems like the problem is caused by:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.Exception: s5.k: An internal error has occurred. [ Instantiation of JsonResponse failed! class com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.l0 ]
```

What I have done is adding:

```
-keep class com.google.android.gms.internal.** { *; }
```

to the `proguard-rules.pro`

Comment: Good to hear that you solved it, Gastón.

Comment: These ProGuard rules should be added by Google

Comment: Yes, thats why I updated my auth dependencies first before posting the question, but seems like they are not added yet. So, for the quick solution and in order to create a release apk that does not crash, use the solution above